# AppSheet + Spreadsheet: AppSheet won't display formulaically generated image

Tags: image, spreadsheet, qr-code, array-formulas, google-appsheet

I am stuck on this problem and request your guidance. Appreciate it in advance!

I am trying to display QR code images on the Appsheet. The images need to come from spreadsheet where they are stored in a column named QR code. The QR codes are unique for each row and are formulaically generated by an array formula in the first row of this column like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank($A$2:$A), "", image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&$A$2:$A)))
```

In the appsheet I have tried making this column of type image, drawing, thumbnail etc. But none of it is working.

I read somewhere that such dynamically generated images don't work with appsheet. It would be really a bummer for me.

I also explored an option to add one more column in the spreadsheet where the image.png could be statically stored somehow. But I was not successful in that.

It would be really great if you could please help me solve this problem.
Thank you so much folks!

Comment: Anyone please? It's a crucial feature for this voluntary work that I am doing for this non-profit. Sincerely appreciate! Also thank you Pradeep Kumar!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the formula in your spreadsheet

=ArrayFormula(image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl="&$A$2:$A))

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrfPldfrOcc

Comment: Hi CDI, I'm already doing that in my spreadsheet as explained in my question. I want to fetch those QR codes that are pre-generated in the spreadsheet and display that same QR code into Appsheet app. You know what I'm saying? Hope this will help clarify my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same use case with one of my projects and as much as we wanted to utilize a dynamic function like the `ARRAYFORMULA`, unfortunately AppSheet can't properly process this as of the moment. You can refer to this article for more information, [Issues with Google Sheets formulas](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10104397?hl=en).

I've tried your QR generator link and it works just fine, I suggest that you fill in each and every cell for the image to load properly, you can try having helper columns as alternative for the `ARRAYFORMULA`, its a bit tedious at first but it worked for me.

Hope this helps.